# Why is Eclipse looking for nexus-maven-repository-index.zip when trying to update Nexus indexer?

Tags: eclipse, maven, nexus, maven-indexer

I am using Eclipse Oxygen, and I have installed Nexus OSS Repository Manager. At Window->Preferences->Maven I have checked Download repository index updates on startup.

On startup Eclipse is trying to updated index for Nexus and it takes a while. But after that I am getting an error saying that it is unable to update index for nexus.

From the log I am extracting relevant lines:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.m2e.logback.appender 4 0 2017-07-04 10:55:22.312
!MESSAGE Unable to update index for nexus|http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/groups/public/: .m2\repository\.cache\m2e\1.8.0\33b5073b9c3fc53d62eb8dc83e442c3d\nexus-maven-repository-index.zip (The system cannot find the file specified)
!STACK 0
java.io.FileNotFoundException: .m2\repository\.cache\m2e\1.8.0\33b5073b9c3fc53d62eb8dc83e442c3d\nexus-maven-repository-index.zip (The system cannot find the file specified)...
```

When I try to start new Maven project and choose Nexus Indexer as the Catalog I am getting the error message: `No archetypes currently available. The archetype list will refresh when the indexes finish updating.`

I am interested in why is Eclipse looking for nexus-maven-repository-index.zip instead of nexus-maven-repository-index.gz?

In the folder .m2\repository.cache\m2e\1.8.0\33b5073b9c3fc53d62eb8dc83e442c3d\ I have three files: nexus-maven-repository-index.gz (360 MB), nexus-maven-repository-index.properties (180 B) and chunks.lst (0B). No nexus-maven-repository-index.zip.

I have searched for solution on the Stackoverlow, tried lots of things, made some improvements on this issue (which was even worse than now), but did not solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The log message is misleading.  Nexus will try to download that file if the other index files fail to download.  So you'll see that line if it can't download the .gz files.